# Rails Devise User both belongs_to and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

After spending a few days of trying to find an answer online, I figured I should ask for help. I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement these relationships using Rails Associations.

I have 4 models: `User`, `Transfer`, `Building` and `Bag`.

A `User` has a `role` attribute. The possible values for `role` are `'admin'`, `'building_contact'` and `'guest'`.

This is what it looks like in a tree structure. The `Admin`, `Guest` and `BuildingContact` is the role of a `@user`:

```
           Admin
             |
         Transfer
        /        \
     Guest     Building
       |          |
      Bag     BuildingContact
```

Therefore:

`Admin has_many :transfers`
`Transfer belongs_to :admin`

`Transfer has_many :guests`
`Guest belongs_to :transfer`
`Guest has_many :bags`

`Transfer belongs_to :building`
`Building has_many :transfers`
`Building has_many :building_contacts`

**What is the best way to implement the relationship with the `User` model?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the fundamental questions that I'd as is:

Will a user have more than one role? I'm guessing not, since you have a single role attribute. They may share many things, but I'd say that the business logic for the different user types would create different models. How about ditching that role attribute and instead using a type attribute and using STI?

```
class Admin < User; end
class Guest < User; end
class BuildingContact < User; end
```

That way you will have the inherited User capabilities but you can define differing business logic where appropriate. You can extend this into different controllers and views, otherwise I would think you would risk having a much bigger User class than you would want to.

Comment: That's perfect! I had that idea last night but didn't know what it was called. So I stayed with the way I was doing it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.